# how persistent is contacts LOOKUP_KEY?

Tags: android, android-contacts, lookup

In my app, I want to assocate contacts with other data.  The reference to the contact must be as persistent as possible, otherwise the associated data becomes rubbish.

First, am I correct that I should use ContactsContract.Contact.LOOKUP_KEY to access an aggegrate contact?

Assuming the above, then, how persistent is the LOOKUP_KEY?  I would like to presume that it stays valid as long as at least one of the underlying raw tables persists.  In particular, I'd like it to be persistent regardless if the user:
- changes the name in any of the raw tables
- removes it from a raw table (but not from all raw tables)
- adds it independently to a new raw table.

Are my assumptions valid?  If not, any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: I am in exactly the same scenario as you. Has `LOOKUP_KEY` been working for you, or did you find a better way to reference contacts?

Comment: It seems to work as long as the user doesn't clear and reload contacts.  The key is not a GUID.  It gets recomputed when you reload contacts.  It may also get recomputed when it merges contacts from two sources - e.g. gmail and facebook.  All and all, it is not long term reliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, anything in ContactsContract.Contact is for an aggregate contact.

LOOKUP_KEY persists as long as the aggregate contact itself is there. Use CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI to do queries against ContactsContract.Contact whenever possible.

Are you running into problems?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't persist. I've discovered that if you make changes to the contact name, the LOOKUP_KEY changes.  To a certain degree, it appears to be similar enough that using it in a future lookup seems to work, but I imagine that can't be guaranteed.

Comment: Furthermore, if the user clears the contact storage and resyncs, the lookup_key values can be completely different.